# How to install private apps using Android Management API?

Tags: google-colaboratory, android-management-api, android-enterprise

I have made the application available to the organization in Google Play Store.

I am using Android Management API to install the application in the device. The public apps are getting installed but the private app is not getting installed.
I am getting the following nonComplianceDetails when calling https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=enterprises/*}/devices  API

"nonComplianceDetails": [
        {
          "settingName": "applications",
          "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
          "packageName": "com.xyz.abc",
          "installationFailureReason": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities",
          "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
          "packageName": "com.xyz.abc"
        }
      ]

Am I missing something in the policy?

I am not able to view the app in the device play store. App is not getting installed also. And when I am giving installType as KIOSK a page is comming which shows 'Installing work apps'. And never gets installed. Also the app is approved in managed Play Store Enterprise.

Comment: There is currently a bug in Android Management API that does not let install private apps in KIOSK mode. First, you have to use "installType": "AVAILABLE" policy to configure the phone, and after it's configured change the policy to "installType": "KIOSK".  I spent days banging my head because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your private app is distributed properly to your enterprise. You can check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9495634?hl=en#) on how to properly distribute your private app to an enterprise.

The non-compliance indicates that the installation is still in [progress](https://developers.google.com/android/management/eap/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices?hl=en#installationfailurereason). This app could take a while to install depending on the size of the app and network connection speed.